# How do I raise PDOException?

Tags: php, exception, pdo

This code works fine, but I'll want to handle `exception` if any thing goes wrong, so I deliberately made a syntax error in the `query` but nothing happens. Below is the code

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO journals (topic, author, ) VALUES ('$topic', '$authors', ')";
    echo "1st";
    $lecturers_db->query($sql);
    echo "second";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo $msg = "Error!";
}
```

Without the obvious syntax error, the code works fine but with the syntax error, nothing happens, all the code in the `try block` executes and the code in the `catch block` never executes.

I want to raise an `exception`, please how do I do it here, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure to set the attribute **PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE** to **PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION**, as soon as you init your pdo object:

```
$lecturers_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

After that, any failed queries will raise an exception

Comment: +1 You could also pass this as the fourth argument to the constructor: `array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )` (along with possible other configuration options).

Comment: @Chibuzo Glad to be of help :) If this was useful, dont forget to mark it as answered, Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Exceptions are thrown.  Syntax errors in code != Exceptions.

```
<?php 
    try {
        $code = 12;
        throw new PDOException('Message', $code );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

    }
?>
```

However, from the [maual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php):

> You should not throw a PDOException from your own code. See Exceptions
>   for more information about Exceptions in PHP.

My advice is to throw either a general exception, or to write your own custom exception to handle your error.

Comment: Thank you very much for input, I follow your link.

Comment: You misunderstood OP's question. He was talking about syntax errors in the SQL statements. It took me a second read as well to figure that out.

Comment: @fireeyedboy yeah I noticed that after I read marcelog's answer.  thanks for pointing it out