# Getting a basic PDO statement to execute

Tags: php, pdo

I am attempting to get the following PDO statement to work and running into issues.  When I am trying to get the number of rows, I keep getting 0, yet I know there should be 1 row.  When I ran it as a mysqli statement( before trying to change it to PDO) it worked perfectly.
Here is the code:

```
    require_once ('pdo.php');
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
    // check to see if the isbn is a "problem" isbn or not
$problem = $conn->prepare("select isbn, note from problem where isbn = :isbn");
$problem->bindParam(":isbn", $isbn);
$problem->execute();
print_r($problem);

$num_rows = $problem->rowCount();

print_r($num_rows); die;
```

EDIT: Here is pdo.php:

```
    <?php

function db_connect()
{ 
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; db=bookcell_BCOS_final", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
return($db);
}
?>
```

I know that my connection works, but I get 0 for $num_rows.  What mistakes am I making here?

Comment: Can you post what's in `pdo.php` (but xxx out any passwords or domains)?

Comment: Why are you using `columnCount()` when you are looking for the number of rows?

Comment: `columnCount()` is not the number of rows. You mean `rowCount()`.

Comment: thanks, I changed it to rowCount.

Comment: I did not check if this can be in fact a problem but in the connection string for pdo I am using dbname and not db to specify the name of the database I want to use.. you should set error handling to throwing exceptions and enclose both the connection attempt and the query in try/catch blocks to have a better knowledge of your problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides a little quirk and a optimalisation your code looks fine to me. The posted value `isbn` could be the reasong that you are getting no data:

```
$problem = $conn->prepare("select isbn, note from problem where isbn = :isbn"); 
$problem->bindParam(":isbn", $_POST['isbn'], PDO::PARAM_STR); // <-- thats what parameter binding is for 
$problem->execute(); 
print_r($problem); 

$num_rows = $problem->rowCount(); // <-- gives the number of rows, not columnCOunt 

print_r($num_rows); die;
```

Comment: thanks, I think it was finally the PDO::PARAM_STR that did the trick.

Comment: Do I need to use that with every statement?

Comment: If the binding is not clear, then define the type. Usually it defaults to string, and it works without the type. If you can, provide it. I think a isbn number was difficult to default and therefore you needed to specify,

Comment: this does not work because: CDbConnection and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "prepare".

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax for `$num_rows = $problem->columnCount();` is totally correct. You may try,

```
$problem->execute(array("isbn" => $isbn));
```

instead of `bindParam`.

Answer (score 0):

for getting the no. of rows, you need to use `pdo::rowCount()` -- [manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

In PDO to verfiy if your [`execute` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) did work, check the return value (bool):

```
$success = $problem->execute();

if (!$success) {
    $arr = $problem->errorInfo();
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Also you might be looking for `rowCount()` instead of `columnCount()` but I think the error handling is your furthermost issue.

Additionally you can make PDO throw an exception each time an error appears, compare:

- [Switching from PHP's mysql extension to PDO. Extend class to reduce lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183695/switching-from-phps-mysql-extension-to-pdo-extend-class-to-reduce-lines-of-cod/12192062#12192062)
- [How do I raise PDOException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050736/how-do-i-raise-pdoexception)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database driver and the mode it's running, PDO may not be able to give you a row count. Look carefully at [the documentation for `PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. **However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.**

This is because in many cases the database uses a cursor rather than fetching the full results and buffering them (which is how the old `mysql_*` functions behave). In this case the database doesn't know how many rows there are until you have looked at all the rows. Think of a cursor as something like a filesystem pointer--you can't know the filesize until you seek to the end of the file.