# How can I handle errors when there is transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my code:

```
try {
    $dbh_con->beginTransaction();

        $stmt1 = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE activate_account_num SET num = num + 1");
        $stmt1->execute();

        $stmt2 = $dbh_con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM activate_account WHERE token = ?");
        $stmt2->execute(array($token));
        $num_rows = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ( $num_rows['user_id'] ){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'all fine';

        } else {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'token is invalid';
        }

    $dbh_con->commit();

    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $dbh_con->rollBack();

    $_SESSION['error'] = 'something is wrong';
    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();
}
```

As you see, my script rollbacks all queries when there is a exception. But it doesn't rollback when `if ( $num_rows['user_id'] ){` is `false`. So how can I both rollback the queries and keep the error `'token is invalid'` when that condition is `false` ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050776/2397327) to throw an exception

Comment: put your modification out of the try-catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just throw an Exception and catch it like you already do. But instead of one catch statement have two:

```
try {
    $dbh_con->beginTransaction();

        $stmt1 = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE activate_account_num SET num = num + 1");
        $stmt1->execute();

        $stmt2 = $dbh_con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM activate_account WHERE token = ?");
        $stmt2->execute(array($token));
        $num_rows = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ( $num_rows['user_id'] ){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'all fine';

        } else {
            throw new \Exception('token is invalid');
        }

    $dbh_con->commit();

    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

$dbh_con->rollBack();

$_SESSION['error'] = 'something is wrong';
header('Location: /b.php');
exit();
} catch(Exception $e) {

    $dbh_con->rollBack();

    $_SESSION['error'] = 'token is invalid';
    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Wrong .. in this `$_SESSION['error']` will be containing `something is wrong`, not `token is invalid`.

Comment: Then simply remove `$_SESSION['error'] = 'token is invalid';` and just throw your exception

Comment: Why? I need three error messages .. `all fine`, `token is invalid`, `something is wrong` ..! Throwing an exception lets me to have only two error messages. While I need to handle three error messages.

Comment: I strictly does not recommend using general \Exception in this case, more likely create your own Exception something like DatabaseProblemException. Because in this case, when you try to catch all types of exception you dont get any log information and you can simply hide other errors in your code which you like to get. For example, if you will have typo in your table_name instead of getting clearly error message "Table activate_acount does not exists", you will be looking at "Something is wrong". And it will cost you time to find out why.

Comment: I updated the answer to allow you to have two different error messages. An alternative would be to check the type of exception and tailor your message that way.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes , now your code works as expected .. upvote. Just what about using a redirect code in that `else` block? Like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/24515ced3191a6a7923a3411a625f492) .. Noted that it works as expected but I'm not sure it is standard, is it?

Comment: If you need to rollback the first UPDATE then that won't work. Otherwise it's a matter of preference and how your app is architected.

Comment: @JohnConde If I write a redirect code in the `else` block, that `UPDATE` statement **will be** rollback. Yes that's odd to me too .. ! But that happens. Actually it surprisingly happens.

Comment: btw can't I use `$e` as the value of `$_SESSION['error']` ?

Comment: `$e` will contain an exception object. So you would need to use `$e->__toString()`.

Comment: I marked your solution as accepted answer .. because it's actually the most standard one. Just for my information, are you believe my approach is wrong *(that one which I linked)*? Also please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579529/how-pdo-rollbacks-the-queries-before-executing-rollback-function) to be sure that `UPDATE` will be rollback.

Answer (score 1):

Your order of operations isn't good.  You're making changes in the DB before you validate the token. This is bad security design.  Always validate all inputs first, and only then make changes.

Secondly, the `SELECT` query that fetches the tokens doesn't need to be part of a transaction. Rolling back a `SELECT` has no impact because such a query makes no change to the DB. So I would do

```
try{
   select token
   if token is not found, set error and exit

   begin transaction
   update active_account_num
   ...other queries?
   end transaction and commit

   set success message, set header & exit
}catch{
   rollback
   set error message, set header & exit
}
```

In this case, because there is only one query that can change the DB, you don't even need a transaction.

Comment: Your approach will work just in that example which is in my question. In reality my code is more complicated and your approach isn't useful.

Comment: Sorry buddy .. + for this answer because it works for the mentioned example.

Comment: @stack no need to apologize!  I just wanted to help.

Comment: That's very nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier, if you do the update after making sure that the table contains the values of interest

```
try {
    $stmt2 = $dbh_con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM activate_account WHERE token = ?");
    $stmt2->execute(array($token));
    $num_rows = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ( $num_rows['user_id'] ){
        $dbh_con->beginTransaction();
        $stmt1 = $dbh_conn->prepare("UPDATE activate_account_num SET num = num + 1");
        $stmt1->execute();

        $_SESSION['error'] = 'all fine';
        $dbh_con->commit();

    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'token is invalid';
        /* no transaction here, nothing to rollback */
    }

    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    $dbh_con->rollBack();

    $_SESSION['error'] = 'something is wrong';
    header('Location: /b.php');
    exit();
}
```

The calls to exit() are redundant too and can be removed.

Comment: Your approach will work just in that example which is in my question. In reality my code is more complicated and your approach isn't useful.

Comment: obviously we can only mak e our answer based on your question we cannot devine your real code. Questions of this nature are magnets for down votes and close votes

Comment: You are right .. but my code in reality is really huge and hard-to-understand *(even hard-to-read)*. That's why I simplified it ..

Comment: yes but to say this wont work because this is not my real code is to waste everyone's time

Comment: Sorry buddy .. + for this answer because it works for the mentioned example.

Comment: Very kind of you :)